# C# Chart not showing Series after changing X Axis Type from String to DateTime

Tags: c#, charts, graphics

the title Pretty much says it all.

I have a Chart in my C# WinForms application, which has 3 series, 1 X Axis and 2 Y Axis.
First I passed my data to the Series Points with X: String, Y: Double, Y2, Double and everything worked fine.

But since the String on the X axis has Always been a DateTime, I'm now using DateTime.ParseExact.
It's parsing correctly but when I try to open the Chart again, it just Shows an empty Chart (With correct begin and ending of X-, Y- & Y2-Axis-Ranges)

I hope this was enough description since I cant Show you any Code.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: X-axis should basically never be strings, unless the values have no bearing on the chart (Like IDs or counrty codes) so your chart may have had problems before even with datapoints showing. But what really happens we can't know without code (especially the lines that addd the data) and without images of the chart before and after the changes. Note that uinless you use DateTime values directly you need to change datetime to double with ToOADate function

Comment: Also with ToOADate it won't work, but even in Debugging the Points of my series are set correctly it just won't Show in my graphical Chart. Color& everything else should be set correctly to make the Lines visible

Comment: It is certainly about the actual x-values. Use the debugger to see what is in there and compare it to the axis ranges! Any reason why you 'can't' show any code?

Comment: _I pass the datetime as a string_ Never do that! It only looks like it is working but all you really see are evenly spaced labels. Add them as (correct) datetimes. Until you get the hang of it do not yet set and ranges on the axis!

Comment: When using the DateTime as a String, the X-Axis-Values are Always 0, but are visible in the Chart.
When using the DateTime as DateTime object, the X-Axis values are 40000+ but Nothing in the Chart.
The "Maximum" property of the AxisX is NaN.

What's confusing that even when using DateTime directly, it doesn't Show any lines in the Chart, but it correctly detects Maximum&Minimum in the visual Chart.

The reason I Can't Show anything is because it's Code from my Job and we're denied to share any Kind of Code external

Comment: Well ok, but it is a common mistake and the solution always is: Add them as DateTime. Then look at the values! The data-> double function will tell you why the data somehow are outside of the range. Also: When you tell the chart that the axis contains datetimes (as you should) it will trust you and then all the 0-values will not only be at the beginning of time (00:00:00 (midnight), January 1, 0001 Anno Domini (Common Era)) but also on the very same position..

Comment: Na, lefft's etz?

Comment: Hmm, when adding it as DateTime, all X values are 40000 and more, no 0 value, but it's still not showing, but the Chart correctly detects the Minimum and Maximum date on the X axis

Comment: Now I've tested changing the values from ~40000 to 1, 2 and 3, and it now Shows in the Chart. But the range of X Axis is wrong now, before it correctly showed some days in August, now it Shows 1st of January etc.

Comment: Zur Orientierung : `44068,3757839815 = 25.08.2020 09:01:07` und morgen `44069,3757839815 = 26.08.2020 09:01:07`

Comment: Ja, die Werte liegen an sich nicht weit auseinander, immer nur ein paar Tage, allerdings scheint der Chart ein Problem damit zu haben dass die Zahl an sich 44k so groß ist oder was weiß ich. Wie schon gesagt mit verfälschten Werten von 1,2 & 3 funktioniert es, nur halt dass das Datum logischerweise irgendwas mit Januar ist

Comment: _die Zahl an sich 44k zu groß_ Nein, nein. Die Chart kommt damit prima klar, das ist ja ihr Job. Wenn du in ein Testprogramm DateTime Werte direkt einfügst ohne sonstwas zu machen siehst du dass das automatisch klappt. NaN ist der Wert für Maximum/Minimum etc um die Automatik (wieder) zu aktivieren. Du hast vermutlich irgendwelche Einstellungen, die die Automatik unterlaufen.